# Microsoft Graph "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again" in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, permissions, microsoft-graph-api

I am unable to list events in a calendar via MS Graph API: calls result in "Access is denied". Switching to raw HTTP results in error 403 as well. I am able to create an event via a POST to /events endpoint, though.

This is the code I am executing:

```powershell
$tenant = '<SNIP>'
$client_id = '<SNIP>'
$client_secret = '<SNIP>'
$scope = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode('https://graph.microsoft.com/.default') 
$url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenant/oauth2/v2.0/token"
$Body = "client_id=$client_id&scope=$scope&client_secret=$client_secret&grant_type=client_credentials"

$response = Invoke-RestMethod  $url -Method Post -Body $Body -Headers @{'Content-Type'='application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
$token = $response.access_token 

Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken  $token

Get-MgUserEvent -UserId  '17160c5f-dd86-46cc-92b8-54d6e94861e6'
```

Output:

```
.\Calendar.ps1
Welcome To Microsoft Graph!
Get-MgUserEvent : Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.
In C:\Users\SYSTOLA-rk\Calendar.ps1:15 Zeichen:1
+ Get-MgUserEvent -UserId  '17160c5f-dd86-46cc-92b8-54d6e94861e6'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: ({ UserId = 1716..., Property =  }:<>f__AnonymousType39`7) [Get-MgUserEvent_List1], RestException`1
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ErrorAccessDenied,Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Cmdlets.GetMgUserEvent_List1
```

Here are the permissions in Azure configured for the app (I lack reputation for posting images): [App Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4c65i.png)

Comment: Your body is missing some parameter according to MS website : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts.  For array I use parenthesis instead of curly brackets : @(...........) not @{..............}

Comment: It is not the `Invoke-RestMethod` that gives an error, it is `Get-MgUserEvent` that is faulting. The body is correct for application auth and curly braces construct the header collection, not an array, so this is correct as well. In any case the token gets acquired and can be used for some things. But access to Calendar is denied.

Comment: Is it possible there's an [application access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access) in place that's limiting the access?

Comment: I have not created any. Are there any policies that are created per default in Exchange online?

Comment: Read following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/get-started?view=graph-powershell-1.0

Comment: No there's no default policies, possible someone else created one? The only way I can reproduce the error is if I remove the permission, but the configuration in your image should work (only `Calendars.Read` is required). Check the token used in the request (`$error[0].Exception.RequestMessage.Headers.Authorization.Parameter`) actually contains the permission

Comment: @scottwtang, with the acquired token I can create an event, but not list them, so somehow I get a write-only access.

Comment: @jdweng I have read this a couple of times already. If you see what is wrong here, I will gladly hear you out, but so far I am not sure what exactly you are referring to.

Comment: The link I provided says the Access Token is added to the HTTP Header.  You are adding the OATH2 token to the body.  There is more than one way of adding tokens.  You may be using a different method than webpage wants.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts#access-tokens  The link is from 12/20/22.  It looks like it is recent.  So if you are following an older set of documentation it may not be current.

Comment: The top of page show the request with the following tags : 1)client_id 2)scope 3) code 4) redirect_url 5) grant_type 6) client_secret   You request is missing "code"  The code looks like it is the token.  You have the token as a parameter which was probably changed because it is less secure.

Comment: @jdweng He is using the PowerShell module which acts as a wrapper for the API. You can see he only passes the token when calling the `Connect-MgGraph` cmdlet, which in turn automatically passes the token through to any further API calls. And the `code` property is only used for the `authorization code` flow, which is a delegated flow that involves a user. OP is using the `client credential` flow without a user. OP's code works fine.

Comment: @scottwtang : Then why did op post this question if code is working?  there is no API calls for the connection.  OP must insert the HTTP Header and Body correctly.  As I said it looks like there was a change at MS Graph to make connection more secure and probably the CMDLET is not current.

Comment: @jdweng The code can work fine while having a different issue, for example incorrect permissions applied on the app registration. Have you actually even tried running the code? Because it works fine. Or provide a specific example of how you think the request should be formed

Comment: @RomanKuznetsov I was able to replicate the error, after adding all 3 `Calendar` permissions you have. I was able to resolve the error by removing the `Calendars.ReadBasic.All` permission

Comment: @scottwtang Yes! that works! Thank you so much! I would not have thought that "ReadBasic" permission would interfere with the flow. If you create an answer, I can then credit you with a successfully answered questions.

Comment: @jdweng As scottwtang pointed out, this was a permission problem, but the flow itself was a so-called application flow, which is a user-less approach, hence it might look different to what you were expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue as we found is that the `Calendars.ReadBasic.All` permission was causing a conflict with the other `Calendar` permissions. Removing this permission resolved the error